# Selenium Webdriver Modal not appearing when automated

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, modalpopupextender

I am writing automation code using Selenium Webdriver Java against an application for Point of Sales systems.

When the application opens up at first there is a modal dialog which appears for the user to select an item on.  This modal appears no problem when testing manually.  Until just recently it also appeared when running automation.

It no longer does.  The behavior is different between manual and automated runs.

I'm running against Chrome and I've set the "disable-popup-blocking" option for the Chrome driver, but it doesn't seem to be helping.

The developers also have no idea what might have changed.  I am at a loss and just looking for any thoughts about where to look for clues.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to address your query:

1. `The behavior is different between manual and automated runs` is factually incorrect statement until & unless you are controlling the WebDriver instance with arguments.
2. As you mentioned `there is a modal dialog` which significantly means that the code for the dialog is present in the DOM. Maybe it's within​ a frame which we have to find out.
3. `"disable-popup-blocking" option for the Chrome` - The purpose of this option have nothing to do with element present in the HTML DOM.
4. Amidst all the confusion, the best solution may be to take help of Selenium Builder & put an end to all guesses.

Let me know if this answers your question.